# How can I make a diagram for a DWT in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-trees, tikz-cd

I would like to make a similar diagram like next figure using package tikz-cd in overleaf.
[image]

I can make this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{article}
% ------------ Packages ------------ %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{tikz-cd}    
% --------------------------------------
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzcd}[cramped, column sep=tiny]
1 \arrow[to=d21, dashed]& 1 \arrow[to=d21, dashed]\\
&|[alias=d21]| 0\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But can't centralize it. So, how can I do it in LaTeX? I thought add another column like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{article}
% ------------ Packages ------------ %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{tikz-cd}    
% --------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
1  \arrow[to=d21, dashed] && 1 \arrow[to=d21, dashed]\\
&|[alias=d21]| 0\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But this is counter-productive if I need to add other lines.

Furthermore, I wasn't able to insert coefficients y_i, d_2, c_2, ..., c_0.

Problems:

1. How can I put the coefficients y_i, d_2, c_2, ..., d_0, c_0 on the right?
2. How can I automatically align the lines like the fist figure?

If necessary to use another package, there’s no problem.

Observation: the dotted arrows depicta subtraction and the solid arrow indicate addition.

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! You say that you can make at least part of the diagram. Could you please edit your code into your question, so that others have a starting point for how to help you?

Comment: Please provide a complete example people can compile. Code fragments aren't very helpful. Can't you just insert another column in the first row in the middle? I.e. `&& 1 ...`.

Comment: Yes I can insert another column in the first row, but this is inconvenient to make all diagram. If i need to add or remove lines I will need edit all lines. I will edit the post. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @JoãoSiqueira, what are your boundary conditions or requirments? E.g. do you need to use tikz-cd, or are you basically free? How large can the diagram grow? // Please, right from the start, begin all your posted codes with `\documentclass`, end it with `\end{document}`, provide anything in between to make it compile when copied AND showing your current achievments. (Those additions may be obvious here, but its tedious for everyone, and many Latex-questions are more ambiguous than here with Tikz.) // Thanks

Comment: To me, this looks rather like a [tree](https://tikz.dev/tikz-trees), so maybe the `forest` package is a better choice …

Comment: Yesterday, afeter post this question I found this package, but, in this case, has two arrows leaving the "node". I couldn't configure the package for this format. If you have a suggestion, I will appreciate it. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `tikz-cd` is the wrong tool. I suggest using `forest` instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={inner sep=1pt,
    grow'=north, s sep=10mm,
    math content,
    edge={densely dashed,<-},
    if n children=1{for children={no edge}}{},
    if level<=1{no edge}{if n children=2{for children={tikz={\draw[->]()--(!uu);}}}{}}
}
[
[42
    [6
        [18
            [14
                [2
                    [0[1][1]]
                ]
                [16
                    [2[7][9]]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        [24
            [4
                [10
                    [6[2][8]]
                ]
                [14
                    [-2[8][6]]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
[c_0[d_0[c_1[d_1[c_2[d_2[y_i]]]]]]]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```